# How do I get the Atlas Pass V2 and V3?

Tags: no-mans-sky

There have been a lot of people that have been researching and asking online about how to get the Atlas Passes V2 and V3, but none have been much help or are inaccurate, so I will post how I received them as an answer.

Comment: Note: If you find the V3 blueprint, you can stop, as the V3 pass will open V2 doors as well. Don't throw away your V1 though. I found out shortly after I did that V3s will *only* open V2/V3, not V1.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for adding that information.

Answer (score 13):

To gain the Atlas passes V2 and V3 you must deploy a signal scanner (orange rays of light shining up to the sky) and upon interacting with it you then need to select colonial outpost. At this point it will give you a waypoint called either "Manufacturing Facility" or "Operations Centre". The Operations Centre is the only one that can potentially have the Atlas Passes (as one might expect since they are the rarer of the two that show up on most planets).

Once you arrive you will need to destroy the door to gain access to the building (if you go straight inside the sentinels will leave you alone). You then need to access the database and select the right answer. If you do not get either of the Atlas Passes do not be worried you are doing it correct, you just need to keep doing these steps until you find the correct blueprints.

TIPS: When I found them it gave me two options and they were V3 was the bottom option and the V2 was the top option (they are not the same, you will have to carry on until you find the other version, unless you are lucky enough to get V3 on your first try, which opens ALL Atlas doors, but not V1 Atlas debris canisters, so keep your V1 pass if you want to continue opening those).

That's how you gain access to the Atlas Pass V2 and V3.

Comment: Do you need to reach a certain milestone or progress in the "story" to some point to enable this? I visited tons of factories and got lots of blueprints for crafting stuff but never an Atlas Pass. Since I have not progressed too much I think that might be the reason.

Comment: No it doesn't matter about the progression, it took me a while about 2 days to get them so just keep at it. You will eventually find them.

Comment: You probably need to get the Atlas Pass from a spatial anomaly first. I've done days of operations centers and manufacturing facilities and not seen an atlas pass, but I'd avoided the atlas storyline completely until now. After getting the v1 then the v2 popped up.

Answer (score 4):

Polo will eventually give you Atlas Pass v2 and v3, but [only after many tasks](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Polo). The 12th reward Polo gives is Atlas Pass v2 in exchange for having Ships Destroyed level 8. The 14th reward is Atlas Pass v3 in exchange for Extreme Survival 7.

In addition [people report](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4yf4p8/tip_for_getting_atlas_pass_v2_v3_from_outposts/) randomly finding the v2 or v3 passes in Operations Centers in Korvax systems, after choosing to Silicate and getting a blue blueprint reward.

Answer (score 1):

I got the v2 from Polo after turning in the Pirate (starships destroyed milestone 8 or above) data, in a space anomoly.